# does manual triggering of a airflow DAG interfere with the scheduled airflow trigger?

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to use airflow DAG to run some jobs. I have scheduled the expression to every 25 mins, like `*/25 * * * *`.  for instance, it seems to run, like at 6:25, 6:50, and at 7 as well, but I want to run it at 7:15, not at 7.

as an alternative, I want to know, if I manually trigger a DAG, will the next trigger be affected by this, like will the next trigger be delayed, or will it continue on its own schedule.

The airflow *version* I am using is `1.10.4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been maintaining a daily schedule .

Manually triggering a DAG does not impact the scheduled triggering of the Airflow DAGs. It will continue to run as per schedule .

Answer (score 2):

Although the accepted answer is correct, It may help someone knowing that on Airflow  `v2.0.0` there was a bug that caused exactly the opposite. Manually triggered DAGs did interfere with the scheduled execution.
Gracefully that bug was fixed on `v2.0.1`, details on the issue [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13434).

Hope that helps, it took me a while to figure it out!